# Connect my node js app from heroku to my Mysql db on godaddy

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, heroku, vps

I'm trying to connect my node java-script back end to my angular front end that's hosted on go-daddy but apparently node java-script isn't supported on go-daddy so i have to use a virtual private network so i used Heroku but when i use Heroku i get an error "Type Error: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined" which means my db-config isn't connected to my MySQL db on go-daddy (PHP my admin) but all the credentials are correct and i know that for sure because I've used them through pure PHP and they worked.

Everything works when i host the node app locally and the mysql db locally.`

below is my dbConfig.js file

```
 const dotenv = require("dotenv");
 
 dotenv.config();

 const host = 'domain name hosting my db';

 const user = 'username';

 const password = 'password';

 const database = 'db name';

 module.exports = { host, user, password, database };
```

below is the connection being created in another file

```
app.get('/students', async (req, res) => {
  const conn = await connection(dbConfig).catch(e => {});
  const results = await query(conn, 'SELECT * FROM students').catch(console.log);
  res.json({ results });
});
```

below is my query.js file

```
module.exports = async (conn, q, params) => new Promise(
(resolve, reject) => {
  const handler = (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
      reject(error);
      return;
    }
    resolve(result);
  }
  conn.query(q, params, handler);
});
```

Comment: Are you using the appropriate connection string? We need to see how you're trying to connect.

Comment: @Cehhiro check edit please, alse everything works locally